# Return if string has 90% of words in an array

Tags: elasticsearch

Im ok at elasticsearch however solving this problem is a bit advanced for me. If I have an array of words, how can I search for documents, that have a string field, that contains say 90% of those words?

eg

```
iKnowTheseWords = ["word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","word7","word8","word9"]

documents = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "content": "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "content": "word1 word2 word3 word4"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "content": "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word11 word12 word13 word14"
  }
]
```

In the above example, I would like documents with the ids 1 and 2 to be returned but not 3 since it has more words than I know and above the 90% threshold (document 1 is fine as I know 90% of those words).

Obviously there are ways to programmatically solve this however I would love to be able to do it at an elasticsearch query level.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I never did this, but i would start by looking at [should in bool queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-bool-query.html) or [constant score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) so you can quantify the score based on the amount of hits

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript using functional programming you can do something like this:

```
var threshold = 0.9; // 90%
var found = documents
   .filter(document => {
      var numberOfWordsFound = iKnowTheseWords
         .reduce((total, word) => {
            var hasWord = document.content.split(word).length > 1;
            return hasWord ? (total + 1) : total;
         }, 0);
      var precentage = numberOfWordsFound / iKnowTheseWords.length;
      return precentage > threshold;
   });
```

The `found` variable will contain all documents which satisfy the threshold.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion however as mentioned I am trying to do this at the elastic search query level rather than in the application